# What format crash utility's disassembler uses to output assembly instructions?

Tags: crash, assembly, gdb, disassembly

Crash utility can disassemble kernel functions. but what format it uses? Which is first, source or destination?

```
inst src, dist
```

or

```
inst dist, src
```

This is what I am asking about:

```
crash> dis sys_signal
0xc0112c88 <sys_signal>:        push   %ebp
0xc0112c89 <sys_signal+1>:      mov    %esp,%ebp
0xc0112c8b <sys_signal+3>:      sub    $0x28,%esp
0xc0112c8e <sys_signal+6>:      mov    0xc(%ebp),%eax
0xc0112c91 <sys_signal+9>:      mov    %eax,0xffffffec(%ebp)
0xc0112c94 <sys_signal+12>:     movl   $0xc0000000,0xfffffff0(%ebp)
0xc0112c9b <sys_signal+19>:     lea    0xffffffd8(%ebp),%eax
```

Answer (score 2):

The disassembler generates **AT&T syntax** assembly code, which puts the source first, destination last. (Intel syntax does the opposite, and you can distinguish them based on usage of sigils like `%` and `$` all over the place.)

- AT&T: `mov %srcreg,%dstreg`
- Intel: `mov dstreg, srcreg`

More information:

- https://imada.sdu.dk/Employees/kslarsen-bak/Courses/dm18-2007-spring/Litteratur/IntelnATT.htm